# Safari and z-index positioning of header

Tags: safari, z-index

I've coded this website: https://feetup.com/

All works fine, except that in safari the fixed header at the top hides under the content when scrolling. This happens only the homepage. I tried everything I could find online to fix it, without success.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I tried two ways and it works for me, you can try and pick the most suitable way for your site:

1. Disable `overflow: hidden` on `.hero-index`, the header still remains when it is outside of the hero element.
2. Bring the `<header>` outside and put it above the `<div class="... feetup-hero hero-index">`